# lexicographically smallest palindrome

Tags: java, string, algorithm, lexicographic

Im writing a program where i have to find out if the string can be made a palindrome if it can be made, fill the missing alphabets in a string (represented by a '.' ). However the missing alphabet must be filled in such a way that the resulting palindrome is lexicographically smallest palindrome.I am able to find out the resulting palindrome for an input however i dont understand what is lexicographically smallest palindrome.

Comment: There are multiple ways to convert the string into a palindrome. But your task is to find the palindrome that will be first if you arrange all the possible palindromes in lexicographical (alphabetical) order.

Comment: This is from an ongoing coding contest: https://www.codechef.com/SEPT16/problems/LEXOPAL.  Please don't ask us to solve your contest problem for you while their contest is still live, and make sure to provide attribution for your sources.  (It also violates their rules to ask for outside help.)

Comment: @D.W. Sincere apologies but my intention was to understand the meaning of lexicographically smallest palindrome and not get any coding help and as a matter of a fact i did'nt.I posted my code which was another mistake for which im accountable. i am a new codechef user.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question:

> My question is if put a in all the missing '.' in the string(if it can
>   be made a palindrome) isnt the resulting string lexicographically
>   smallest palindrome?

Well, no.

For example: 
If input is: `cbb.bbc` then output should be `cbbabbc`.
But if input is `df..ffd` then output should be `dffaffd`.
Not all dots are converted into a.

Comment: edited , my program gives the exact answer that you're a suggesting still its not getting accepted.

Comment: ok. Post the code (relevant part) of your program here. Also give the reason why it is not being accepted.

Comment: Added my code and sample inputs and their outputs, the code is not accepted for wrong answer

Comment: Your program looks good. Look for any specific things in the question that you might be missing to comply.

Answer (score 0):

Always filling in a for as the missing character will not always result in the correct solution. Consider the following input

```
a.bc.ba
```

Replacing the dot with 'a' results in

```
aabcaba
```

which is not a palindrome. Instead you need to replace both dots with a 'b':

```
abbcbba
```

The problem becomes even more trickier, if you have more dots, e.g.

```
a.bc.b.a.b.c.a.c.a
```

The lexicographically smallest palindrome is the one where the resulting string, compared to all other possible results, is lexicographically the smallest.

The task might even be more complicated, it you can replace a single dot with multiple characters. You didn't specify the exact conditions, so it's difficult to give a complete answer.

Comment: you still don't specify if a dot can only be replaced by a single letter or if it can be replaced by multiple letters, or can a dot even be replace with no character?